# Traefik 2 howto basicauth non docker service?

Tags: docker, service, basic-authentication, traefik, bare-metal-server

I have a working setup here that uses `dnsmasq` for DNS, runs both a dockerized service (whoami) and a bare metal service (`ruby -run -e httpd . -p 3000`). The configuration redirects to `https` just fine, names resolve just fine.

Also note that I use a secondary IP on a 10.x.x.x network to resolve as `scuar.home` for dns. My local lan resolves 192.169.x.x traffic via dnsmasql -that is all working also. In addition I am using self signed certificates.

My question is, after hours of searching and trial and error: How can I add a `basic auth` to this configuration for the bare metal service?

Here's my **working** config files:

[edit1: added dnsmasq.config in case you want to know how things are resolving]

[edit2: I've added a middlewares section in the router in `traefik-dyn.yml` that **does** give me a login dialog (updated below). However the password doesn't work -so hmmmm.... any help would be appreciated]

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.0"
    # network_mode: host # Allows traefik to talk to your host machine (not necessary we have dnsmasq running)
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      #
      - "${PWD}/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml"
      - "${PWD}/traefik-dyn.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik-dyn.yml"
      #
      - "${PWD}/certs:/etc/traefik/certs"
      - "${PWD}/logs/access.log:/access.log"
    labels:
      # Dashboard (including: dashboard.scuar.lan/api/rawdata -with https redirect)
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      #
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik_https.rule=Host(`dashboard.scuar.lan`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik_https.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik_https.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik_https.tls=true"
      #
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_traefik.rule=Host(`dashboard.scuar.lan`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_traefik.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_traefik.middlewares=https_redirect"
      # auth
      # generate with: echo $(htpasswd -nb admin password) | sed -e s/\\$/\\$\\$/g
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik_https.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=admin:$$apr1$$KPaYkFZF$$1O/da7HYF0eqrWTb.Ig2H0"

      # global HTTP to HTTPS redirect (forces https)
      # accomidates for wildcard host
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{any:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.middlewares=https_redirect"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true"

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami:v1.3.0
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.https_whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.scuar.lan`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.https_whoami.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.https_whoami.tls=true"
      #
      # Same as dashboard auth
      - "traefik.http.routers.https_whoami.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      #
      #This is not necessary: we globally redirect to https/websecure
      # http section not needed with global https redirect
      # - "traefik.http.routers.whoami_http.rule=Host(`whoami.scuar.lan`)"
      # - "traefik.http.routers.whoami_http.entrypoints=web"
      # - "traefik.http.routers.whoami_http.middlewares=https_redirect"
```

traefik.yml

```
#Traefik.yml
# statick Traefik v2 configuration

global:
  sendAnonymousUsage: false

log:
  level: "DEBUG" #INFO #DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
  format: "common"

api:
  insecure: false
  dashboard: true

# accessLog: {}  # use {} for empty placeholder
accessLog:
  filepath: "/access.log"

# allow health check
ping: {}

#Define HTTP and HTTPS entrypoints
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  #Dynamic configuration will come from docker labels
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    network: "docker.devnet"
    exposedByDefault: false
    # domain: "scuar.lan"
    # watch: true
  file:
    # dynamic config file
    filename: "/etc/traefik/traefik-dyn.yml"
    watch: true

##Enable acme with http file challenge
# this is a placeholder as example
# used for let's encrypt (requires net connection)
# certificatesResolvers:
#   le:
#     acme:
#       email: someemail@example.com
#       storage: /acme.json
#       httpChallenge:
#         # used during the challenge
#         entryPoint: insecure
```

traefik-dyn.yml

```
http:
  routers:
    # http-to-myapp:
    # # This is not necessary: we are already redirecting
    #   entryPoints:
    #     - web
    #   rule: "Host(`myapp.scuar.lan`)"
    #   service: "myapp"
    #     - "redirect"


    https-to-myapp:
      rule: "Host(`myapp.scuar.lan`)"
      service: "myapp"
      entryPoints:
        - websecure
      middlewares:
        - "traefik_auth_myapp"
      tls: {}
 
  middlewares:
    traefik_auth_myapp:
      basicAuth:
        users:
          - "admin:$$apr1$$Nzb5.wP6$$ZOnWvJtWujuLLRcYynUSl0"

  # middlewares:
  #   redirect:
  # # This is not necessary: we are already redirecting
  #     redirectScheme:
  #       scheme: "websecure" #works as new entrypoint
  # ##      scheme: "https" #does not work

  services:
    myapp:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://myapp.scuar.home:3000"
        passHostHeader: true

tls:
  certificates:
  - certFile: "/etc/traefik/certs/scuar.lan+1.pem"
    keyFile: "/etc/traefik/certs/scuar.lan+1-key.pem"
```

dnsmasq.conf

```
no-dhcp-interface=
bind-dynamic       # could use bind-interfaces instead 

# localhost
listen-address=127.0.0.1

# scuar.home
listen-address=10.127.127.1
address=/scuar.home/10.127.127.1
domain=scuar.home,10.127.127.0/24

# local machine docker.devnet
domain=docker.devnet,172.17.0.0/24

# scuar.lan
# allow external listeners (local network)
# allow/deny firewall as needed
# sudo ufw <allow|deny> 53; sudo ufw reload
# change IP based on current dhcp connection
listen-address=192.168.1.8
address=/scuar.lan/192.168.1.8
domain=scuar.lan,192.168.1.0/24

## to add this server to another dnsmasq permanently: 
## add this to dnsmasq.conf
# server=/server.lan/192.168.1.8
## otherwise, temporarily, add this to the resolv.conf
#nameserver 192.168.1.8

# standard dns servers for the system level
# btw nework manager has it's own dns settings 
## cloudflare
server=1.1.1.1
## google
server=8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

::sigh:: ok, um, the password hash had too many `$` because I originally copied it from my dockercompose file (which escapes the dollar signs)

I'll just leave this here in case having a working example helps somebody.

Here is the working `traefik-dyn.yml` with functional `basicAuth` for both `@docker` and `@file`. It works in both directions now.

```
http:
  routers:
    # http-to-myapp:
    # # This is not necessary: we are already redirecting
    #   entryPoints:
    #     - web
    #   rule: "Host(`myapp.scuar.lan`)"
    #   service: "myapp"
    #     - "redirect"


    https-to-myapp:
      rule: "Host(`myapp.scuar.lan`)"
      service: "myapp"
      entryPoints:
        - websecure
      middlewares:
        # - "traefik-auth@docker"
        - "traefik-auth-myapp"
      tls: {}

  middlewares:
    traefik-auth-myapp:
      basicAuth:
        users:
        - "admin:$apr1$cDf4FUZs$zbLOgpKvieDPgxQRWsxFH0"

  # middlewares:
  #   redirect:
  # # This is not necessary: we are already redirecting
  #     redirectScheme:
  #       scheme: "websecure" #works as new entrypoint
  # ##      scheme: "https" #does not work

  services:
    myapp:
      loadBalancer:
        passHostHeader: true
        # example service: ruby -run -e httpd . -p 3000
        servers:
          - url: "http://myapp.scuar.home:3000"

tls:
  certificates:
  - certFile: "/etc/traefik/certs/scuar.lan+1.pem"
    keyFile: "/etc/traefik/certs/scuar.lan+1-key.pem"
```

Here's a replacement `docker-compose.yml` with the slight `@file` change to use the dynamic file password.

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.2.8"
    # network_mode: host # Allows traefik to talk to your host machine (not necessary we have dnsmasq running)
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      #
      - "${PWD}/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml"
      - "${PWD}/traefik-dyn.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik-dyn.yml"
      #
      - "${PWD}/certs:/etc/traefik/certs"
      - "${PWD}/logs/access.log:/access.log"
    labels:
      # Dashboard (including: dashboard.scuar.lan/api/rawdata -with https redirect)
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      #
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik_https.rule=Host(`dashboard.scuar.lan`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik_https.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik_https.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik_https.tls=true"
      #
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_traefik.rule=Host(`dashboard.scuar.lan`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_traefik.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_traefik.middlewares=https_redirect"
      # auth
      # generate with: echo $(htpasswd -nb admin password) | sed -e s/\\$/\\$\\$/g
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik_https.middlewares=traefik-auth-myapp@file"
      # - "traefik.http.routers.traefik_https.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=admin:$$apr1$$KPaYkFZF$$1O/da7HYF0eqrWTb.Ig2H0"


      # global HTTP to HTTPS redirect (forces https)
      # accomidates for wildcard host
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{any:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.middlewares=https_redirect"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.https_redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true"

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami:v1.3.0
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.https_whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.scuar.lan`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.https_whoami.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.https_whoami.tls=true"
      #
      # Same as dashboard auth
      - "traefik.http.routers.https_whoami.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      #
      #This is not necessary: we globally redirect to https/websecure
      # http section not needed with global https redirect
      # - "traefik.http.routers.whoami_http.rule=Host(`whoami.scuar.lan`)"
      # - "traefik.http.routers.whoami_http.entrypoints=web"
      # - "traefik.http.routers.whoami_http.middlewares=https_redirect"
```